# How to do integration tests for a lambda that consumes and produces messages to queues

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, integration-testing, amazon-sqs

Suppose we have the following architecture:

[image]

*Bucket A* triggers an event to a queue when a new file is created. *Lambda A* consumes this event and **decides if it should produce a new message to *Queue B***. If *Lambda A* does produce a message to *Queue B*, then *Lambda B* consumes the message and dumps it to a new *Bucket B*.

What is the correct or recommended way to do integration tests for *Lambda A*?

The fact that the message produced by *Lambda A* will be consumed by another lambda when available makes it impossible to check if *Lambda A* produced a message to *Queue B* before the message is gone? How should one handle this in an integration test?

Comment: I'd argue that this is a bit much for an integration test because you're testing a reasonably complex system. As an end-to-end test, you could check if data appears in Bucket B in an acceptable time frame after being uploaded to bucket a. How you test this depends on languages and frameworks none of which you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

> The fact that the message produced by Lambda A will be consumed by another lambda when available makes it impossible to check if Lambda A produced a message to Queue B before the message is gone?

This architecture is actually extremely easy to test, but first you need to answer the question "why test Lambda A in isolation?" An *integration* test should arguably test the entire process end-to-end, and verify that specific inputs (a file uploaded to Bucket A) result in expected outputs (a file in Bucket B). You should have *unit* tests that fully exercise the logic in Lambdas A and B.

But, assuming that you do want to test the output of Lambda A, you just need to provide it with a queue that goes to your test framework rather than Lambda B. If you do want to do an end-to-end-test, then your test framework can take the message and put it on a queue that does go to Lambda B:

```
Queue_A -> Lambda_A -> Test_Queue -> Test Framework -> Queue_B -> Lambda_B
```

This becomes much easier if you write your Lambdas so that they get their queue URLs from environment variables (rather than hardcoded): introducing a test framework then becomes a simple matter of updating configuration rather than code.

And I strongly recommend that you create a dedicated AWS account for integration testing, to avoid accidentally breaking production code.